# RestFB - Picture URL is not properly formatted

Tags: facebook-graph-api, restfb

I'm trying to publish a post on my facebook page using RestFB.

My code is as follows:

```
FacebookType publishResponse =  facebookClient.publish(pageId + "/feed", FacebookType.class,
                Parameter.with("message", message),
                Parameter.with("picture", picture), 
                Parameter.with("link", link), 
                Parameter.with("description", description));
```

And my parameters have the following values:

```
message: Test+test+test
picture: https%3A%2F%2Fcom-smallteaser-local-photo.s3.amazonaws.com%2Fskydivemag%25232fdefcfa-c7b2-4c0d-8504-9942ccd9a4b0%2523648%25230%25232592%25232592%2523292%2523292
link: http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A9000%2Farticle%2F20130503-test-test-test
description: This+is+just+a+test
```

I am getting the exception:

**FacebookOAuthException: Received Facebook error response of type OAuthException: (#100) picture URL is not properly formatted]**

I read [here](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/526/?ref=nf) that i can add a picture with just providing an URL and it specifically says that it is meant for 'App developers who host their images on Amazon S3 or a similar service'.

Any idea what i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think it’s not actually the “formatting” of the picture URL, but the content it returns:

https://com-smallteaser-local-photo.s3.amazonaws.com/skydivemag%232fdefcfa-c7b2-4c0d-8504-9942ccd9a4b0%23648%230%232592%232592%23292%23292

is delivered with a `Content-Type: application/octet-stream` response header ([as you can see here](http://web-sniffer.net/?url=https://com-smallteaser-local-photo.s3.amazonaws.com/skydivemag%25232fdefcfa-c7b2-4c0d-8504-9942ccd9a4b0%2523648%25230%25232592%25232592%2523292%2523292)) – and that might make Facebooks scraper think that this is not really an image resource.

So you will have to figure out how configure your hosting space to deliver these images with a correct `Content-Type`, for example `img/jpeg` or `img/png`.

Comment: OK, so i'm now using image https://com-smallteaser-local-photo.s3.amazonaws.com/skydivemag%2317fae067-0a4e-4be4-b09e-8330df7e97b0%23648%230%232592%232592%23292%23292 but i get the exact same error so i'm guessing something else must be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I got this problem, but only on older Android devices, not on a desktop. I could see in the server logs that there was a difference:

- When accessing the URL on a **desktop**, Facebook **does** request the picture URL.
- When accessing the URL on an **older Android device**, Facebook **does not** request the picture URL.

It turned out that I was using `window.location.origin` in constructing the absolute URL, which according to http://www.hyperink.com/blog/?p=18 only works on Webkit. It was solved by replacing, as the post suggests,

```
window.location.origin
```

by

```
window.location.protocol + “//” + window.location.hostname
```